# Hermite Normal Form

Tags: integer-programming, integer-lattices, hermite-normal-form

Does anyone know an approach to finding the Hermite Normal Form for smaller matrices, like

$
A =\begin{pmatrix}
6 & -6 & 9\\ 3 &2 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$

Or does one just have to shuffle around more or less randomly?

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar algorithm to the usual reduced row echolon form for the Hermite Normal form, see e.g. here on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_normal_form

Comment: I don't see it?

Comment: I recommend the search funciton to search for "Algorithm" on that site. You'll find e.g. [this](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~rojas/kannanbachemhermitesmith79.pdf) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm) one.

Comment: Ah yes, I was hoping for something a little less complex.

Comment: @1233023 If you are not interested in the algorithm itself, Mathematica has a function (called HermiteNormalForm) that you could use.

Comment: @Heterotic Not in my version ( 12. )

Comment: @niloderoock Sorry my mistake, it is called HermiteDecomposition.  https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HermiteDecomposition.html